# extracting two different substrings inside of a string

Tags: regex

**Using regex how do we extract multiple substrings inside of a string?**

Suppose we have this:

> resgrp/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/vvvvvdgdevstor","subject":"/blobServices/default/containers/coloradohhhhready/blobs/README_.._.hl7","eventType":"Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated","eventTime":"2019-06-19T17:28:40.3136657Z","id":"604ad6c5a0145-04c4-26bsssss26a","data":{"api":"PutBlockList","clientRequestId":"aaaaaaae-4e68-95f6-c1ssssb02f"

The result I'd like is:

```
/coloradohhhhready/README_.._.hl7
```

What I've tried is:

```
(?i)(?<=\/containers\/)(.*)(?=\/blobs\/)(.*)(?<=\/blobs\/)(.*)(?=","eventtype)
```

Which yielded:

> coloradohhhhready/blobs/README_.._.hl7

I would simply want to remove the `/blobs/` segment inside of that string:

[image]

Comment: If you don't match the `/` after `/blobs` in your pattern, you could use the first and third capturing group `(?i)(?<=\/containers\/)(.*)(?=\/blobs)(.*)(?<=\/blobs)(.*)(?=","eventtype)` Perhaps you could update your pattern to `(?i)(?<=\/containers)(/[^/]+)/blobs(/[^"/]+)(?=","eventtype")` and use group 1 and group 2.

Comment: Just post-process it: `match = match.Replace("/blobs/", "/")`. Anyway, you cannot match discontinuous text within one match operation into a single group. Lookarounds are not meant to "make holes" in the texts you mach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is this not possible to do with pure regex?

Comment: I think it is clear from my comment.

Comment: from your comment _Anyway, you cannot match discontinuous text within one match operation into a single group. Lookarounds are not meant to "make holes" in the texts you mach._ you are saying that this is simply not possible to do with regex. am i understanding correctly? thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this expression,

```
(?:\/blobs\/)|(.*?)
```

would be maybe an option to start.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ejCW1y/1)

Comment: thanks again for your help, emma, another words this is not possible to do with pure regex?

Comment: that's a really cool solution, however, it looks like it's capturing _everything_ except for `/blobs` https://drive.google.com/uc?id=15mxMKImot48Lj-e_o4wxJSqaKXkVTjLS

Answer (score 2):

If you know you will always want to remove `/blobs/`, then simply replace the whole thing after with a `/`.

On the other hand, pasting your solution on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3k0z6m/1) showed that the match of your epxression yields 3 groups, one of which is `/blobs/`. Thus, in your case it would be as simple as reconstructing another string by doing: `"/" + Group[1].Value + "/" + Group[3].Value`.

Comment: another words you're saying that this is not possible to do with pure regex?

Comment: im interested in a purely regex solution

Comment: the reason this had a .net tag was because i wanted to ensure that the regex was .net-compliant, but since that was confusing, i've removed .net tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match it using a regex, you could use 2 capturing groups and match instead of using lookarounds what comes before, after and `/blobs` in the middle.

In the capturing group `(/[^/]+)` match a forward slash followed by matching not a `/`

Your values are in capturing group 1 and group 2.

```
(?i)(?:/containers)(/[^/]+)/blobs(/[^"/]+)(?:","eventtype")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KrI8jp/1/) | [.NET C# example](https://ideone.com/nLx4A6)

Comment: full match is returning unwanted `/containers/` and `/blobs/` strings: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aMlln70rbrKY4cBHtPY1m6kwvuxQcScy

Comment: thank you i see that, however this is not a purely regex solution `Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value);` i dont want to involve any other code besides regex, not c#